# getting AccessToken, VerifySmsToken mscorlib "Unable to connect to the remote server",

Tags: iis, server, configuration, token, verify

I get this error when I am posting via postman.
Other methods work perfectly. Just this method, that addresses the user verification and its response is an access token, has error.

I think the length of the string token is the origin of the error.

Post man response  :

```
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   at FactoryJaApi.Controllers.UserController.<Login>d__14.MoveNext() \r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at
```

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at FactoryJaApi.Controllers.UserController.d__12.MoveNext() 
        "TargetSite": {
            "Name": "ThrowIfExceptional",
            "AssemblyName": "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

```
        "ClassName": "System.Threading.Tasks.Task",
        "Signature": "Void ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)",
        "Signature2": "System.Void ThrowIfExceptional(System.Boolean)",
        "MemberType": 8,
        "GenericArguments": null
    },
    "ErrorLine": null,
    "ExceptionType": "System.AggregateException",
    "ExceptionUrl": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "DateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Message": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
        "HelpLink": null,
        "Source": null,
        "StackTrace": null,
        "TargetSite": null,
        "ErrorLine": null,
        "ExceptionType": null,
        "ExceptionUrl": null,
        "InnerException": {
            "DateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Message": "Unable to connect to the remote server",
            "HelpLink": null,
            "Source": null,
            "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)",
            "TargetSite": null,
            "ErrorLine": null,
            "ExceptionType": null,
            "ExceptionUrl": null,
            "InnerException": null
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unhandled exceptions in your controllers should be handled by you. That’s usually how 500 errors are caused and fixed.

Comment: No , this Method and this code runs on other server Perfectly ,  I test it several times with several server

Comment: That's a weak statement. Server-server communication differs from machines to machines, as DNS/HTTPS/proxies and other far too many factors can go wrong. If you have access to the problematic server, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing the network tracing should reveal more details. If you don't, then talk to the server administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you that your information does not help me and was far from my ask. 
I pointed this error just happens on verifying and generating token string method. and other method work perfectly and correct.

Token method has a self-Query on itself . so when your query goes to server Kaarix.work , IIS cannot access to same address from interior. for Solving : just you need to define a redirection `local url` and redirect your queries that call from inside machine.

See the screenshot if you need the answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcOIm.png)